# Java agent to transfer lotus notes documents to sqlite doesn't find library

Tags: sqlite, xpages

I am currently using sqllite-jdbc-3.8.11.1.jar in my Java beans to update records in a local sqlite db. That works perfectly fine but the problem is when I try to use the same jar file in a Java agent I get this error message:

> java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Windows and os.arch=x86_64

I checked the jar file and the dll is definitely there.

I have included the jar file in the build path. I added it also as archive in the Java agent but I can't find a reason why it would work in the XPages runtime but not in a Java agent runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your Java agent runs on Notes Client and SQLite is not installed on this local computer.

Run your Java agent on **server** and it should work like for XPages as those get executed on server (except XPiNC).

*Update:*

As you mentioned in your comment dlls are part of JAR file. Java code has to detach and execute dlls. This needs an extended security level. 
Set Properties/Security/Runtime security level to
`3. Allow restricted operations with full administration rights`

You can put a Notes user with full administration rights into field "Run on behalf of" as an alternative or in addition.

Comment: Its a scheduled agent that runs on the server.

Comment: And sometimes you need to edit the java.policy file to grant more access to JVM. E.g. dynamic class loading is one example.

Comment: Yes but why does it work when it runs as a Java bean and but not as a Java agent. Does Domino have different access settings for them.

Comment: The agent is already runngin with option 3 and on behalf of the admin username.

Answer (score 0):

Build path. Do you mean that you have imported the JAR and DLL resources directly to Java agent resources? I think this should work just fine.

Second option is to set the resources on server disc and tell the Domino server to load them from there (notes.ini JavaUserClassesExt setting if I remember correctly).

Comment: The dll's are part of the JAR file. I have used the projects build path to attach the libraries and also the java agents archives which also attaches them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running your java agent locally which will require you to place your JAR in the jvm/ext/lib folder on your pc.  This is the same folder your administrators will have them on the server, but when run on the server you also need to have the JAR included in the build path like you have done.

Watch the recent MWLUG 2015 presentation by Steve Zavocki and myself [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVgfWzBomoM) where we actually provide a little bit of an insight into this or download the slide deck from my [blog](https://xpagesnewbie.wordpress.com/).

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: No its a scheduled agent.

Comment: your Notes admin may need to update the security policy file to grant your JAR the proper permissions